OSError: Not enough disk space. Needed: Unknown size (download: Unknown size, generated: Unknown size, post-processed: Unknown size)
I'm running code using the "load_dataset" function from the Transformer library within a docker environment. However, after a manual interruption, when attempting to load a new JSON file, the following error is reported:
>>> from datasets import load_dataset
>>> data=load_dataset("json",data_files="test.jsonl")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/applications/anaconda3/envs/Gemma/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datasets/load.py", line 2574, in load_dataset
    builder_instance.download_and_prepare(
  File "/home/applications/anaconda3/envs/Gemma/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datasets/builder.py", line 945, in download_and_prepare
    raise OSError(
OSError: Not enough disk space. Needed: Unknown size (download: Unknown size, generated: Unknown size, post-processed: Unknown size)

and the "test.jsonl" is:
  1 {"prompt":"xxxxx","label":"a"}
  2 {"prompt":"xxxyx","label":"b"}
  3 {"prompt":"xyxxx","label":"c"}

What's puzzling is that when I use the "jsonl" file generated before the interruption, it still loads successfully. However, if I try to load a newly created "jsonl" file after the interruption, it will consistently report this error. Even when the contents of both files are identical, their permissions are the same, and they were generated in identical environments.
Moreover, I try to create a new "test.jsonl" file on another docker instance on the same machine, yet encountered the same error upon execution.

I've solved it! Here's the reason:
When the load_dataset method of Hugging Face loads a JSONL file, it automatically caches related files in the .cache/huggingface/datasets/json directory.
However, the physical machine's root disk space is insufficient, causing both dockers to fail to run properly.
Solution:
(1)Instead of using load_dataset, manually read the file and create a dataset using Dataset and DatasetDict. like this:
from datasets import Dataset, DatasetDict
data = [
    {"prompt": "xxxxx", "label": "a"},
    {"prompt": "xxxyx", "label": "b"},
    {"prompt": "xyxxx", "label": "c"}
]
dataset = Dataset.from_dict(data)
dataset_dict = DatasetDict({"train": dataset})

(2)Clean up the .cache/ space or any other file space in the root directory. It's advisable to clear the pip cache and Hugging Face datasets cache.
